# How to Loop through JSON Objects having Objects and Arrays Inside

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api

```js
let mything = {
  "holders": [{
    "address": "0xbe0eb53f46cd790cd13851d5eff43d12404d33e8",
    "balance": 8.623839536582375e24,
    "share": 52.02
  }, {
    "address": "0xf977814e90da44bfa03b6295a0616a897441acec",
    "balance": 4.5e24,
    "share": 27.14
  }]
};

let m = Object.entries(mything);
console.log(m);
```

The above is a json data, stored in a file, now what I want to do is to loop over this whole file which has 2000 of such entries, get just the address part of each entry and append it in a url, so how would I do the looping part??
Any code Snippet for javaScript would be lovely.
Cudos.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried also and your specific challenge with it

Comment: Thank You Mark, for reaching out, my challenge is to get the address value and further use it, and im trying something like Object.entries() method and after that I dont really know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `holders` object is an array, you can loop over it like below, and make use of the address like constructing the URL as per your logic inside the loop. Here's the example of storing the addresses in an array:

```js
var original = {
  "holders": [{
    "address": "0xbe0eb53f46cd790cd13851d5eff43d12404d33e8",
    "balance": 8.623839536582375e24,
    "share": 52.02
  }, {
    "address": "0xf977814e90da44bfa03b6295a0616a897441acec",
    "balance": 4.5e24,
    "share": 27.14
  }]
};

var addresses = [];
for (let holder of original.holders) {
  addresses.push(holder.address);
}
console.log(addresses)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to get a one liner :

```js
const data = {"holders": [{
  "address": "0xbe0eb53f46cd790cd13851d5eff43d12404d33e8",
  "balance": 8.623839536582375e24,
  "share": 52.02
},{
  "address": "0xf977814e90da44bfa03b6295a0616a897441acec",
  "balance": 4.5e24,
  "share": 27.14
}]};

const url = "https://my.url/";
const urls = data.holders.map(holder => `${url}${holder.address}`);

console.log(urls);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = {"holders": [{
  "address": "0xbe0eb53f46cd790cd13851d5eff43d12404d33e8",
  "balance": 8.623839536582375e24,
  "share": 52.02
},{
  "address": "0xf977814e90da44bfa03b6295a0616a897441acec",
  "balance": 4.5e24,
  "share": 27.14
}]};

for(const obj of Object.values(data)) {
    for(const arr of obj) {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const holders = [{
    "address": "0xbe0eb53f46cd790cd13851d5eff43d12404d33e8",
    "balance": 8.623839536582375e24,
    "share": 52.02
}, {
    "address": "0xf977814e90da44bfa03b6295a0616a897441acec",
    "balance": 4.5e24,
    "share": 27.14
}];

const addresses = holders.map((holder) => holder.address);

console.log(addresses);
```